# C++ static evaluation of templated argument

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

Function that I can't seem to get to work:

```
void Add(const Event &event, T callback) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (event == Event::Type1)
        {
            m_type1callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }
        else if constexpr (event == Event::Type2)
        {
            m_type2Callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }
        else if constexpr (event == Event::Type3)
        {
            m_type3Callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }
        else if constexpr (event == Event::Type4)
        {
            m_type4LeaveCallbacks.push_back(callback);
        }
    }
```

Functionality:
Depending on *event* I want to add *callback* to a container of callback-functions

Note:
Each container is templated on **different** templated versions of *std::function<>*

What I want to achive:
The expression to be evaluated at compile time and thus generate function bodies depending on *event*. So, if *m_type1Callbacks* is templated on *std::function*, the function:

```
Add(Event::Type1, [](int foo){std::cout << foo << std::endl;}));
```

should be added to *m_type1Callbacks*

My problem:
When I try the code above I get the error:

```
'event' is not a constant expression
```

What I want help with:
Is my way of solving this problem wrong fundmentally? How should I improve and solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `event` is `const` but not `constexpr`. You can't use a runtime argument in a `if constexpr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `event` a template parameter to your function, you will be able to use it in a `constexpr` context:

```cpp
template <Event event>
void Add(T callback) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (event == Event::Type1)
    {
        m_type1callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    else if constexpr (event == Event::Type2)
    {
        m_type2Callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    else if constexpr (event == Event::Type3)
    {
        m_type3Callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    else if constexpr (event == Event::Type4)
    {
        m_type4LeaveCallbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Thanks for the clarification and the quick answer :)